# Best approach to work with .csv files with 4 gigas

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, visual-studio-code, data-science

I am on data science. I have a .csv file with 5kk records and 3.9gigas of size.  Whats the best pratice to deal with it?  I normally use vscode or jupyter and even when i set max-memory to 10gigas the operations like load etc are taking too much time to complete.

What do you recommend to improve my work?

`notebook lenovo S145 20gigas ram i7-8565U - Ubuntu`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bring a CSV into a database for reporting, one fairly quick and easy option is to use an external table.  It uses syntax similar to `SQLLDR` in the create table definition.  Once established, the latest saved CSV data will immediately be available as a table in the database.

Comment: I was thinking about it. Problem is my csv has 136 columns. guess i need to create a script to take these columns and create a table. its possible right?

Comment: Yes, that should work.  It will be a bit of an effort to get the create table right, but once its working you should be in good shape.  The max number of columns for an external table depends on the database platform.  Looks like Access can take up to 256 columns for an external table - you should be OK with 136..